# Using modal for updating query with php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

[Hello!]
I need help, I'm stuck at this point. I have index.php and m_update_pk.php that i include in index.php! In m_update_pk.php i have modal that opens when someone click on Edit in index table. I want to click on Edit and to open modal with another table in witch i can update my customers. You will see my code, i did everything i know and it isn't working, when i click on Edit nothing happens??
Thanks for helping, i am going crazy

index.php

```
case isset($_GET['poslovni_korisnici']): // Prikaz poslovnih korisnika

        echo'
        <h1>Poslovni korisnici</h1>

        <a href="#insert_poslovni" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-book-id="my_id_value">Unos</a>
        </br>
        </br>';        

        echo'
        <table id="table_id" class="display">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Partner name</th>
                  <th>Partner street</th>
                  <th>Partner zip</th>
                  <th>Partner city</th>
                  <th>Partner country</th>
                  <th></th>
                  <th><a href="edit.php?editPoslovni="><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Delete</button></a></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>';

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM poslovni_partneri";

            foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row)
            {

                echo'
                <tr>
                    <td>'.$row['Partner_name'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['Partner_street'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['Partner_zip'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['Partner_city'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['Partner_country'].'</td>
                    <td><a href="#update_poslovni='.$row['Partner_id'].'" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-book-id="'.$row['Partner_id'].'">Edit</a></td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" id="blankCheckbox" value="option1" aria-label="..."></td>
                </tr>';
            }

            echo'    
            </tbody>
        </table>';

        include 'includes/m_insert_pk.php'; // Insert poslovni korisnici

        include 'includes/m_update_pk.php'; // Update poslovni korisnici

    break;
```

m_update_pk.php

```
    <?php
// ---- Pocetak modal-a za update poslovnih korisnika ---- //
echo'
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" id="update_poslovni">  
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Uredi</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Unos poslovnih korisnika</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">';

      if (isset($_POST['submit_upk'])) {            

            $partnername    = $_POST['partner_name'];
            $partnerstreet  = $_POST['partner_street'];
            $partnerzip     = $_POST['partner_zip'];
            $partnercity    = $_POST['partner_city'];
            $partnercountry = $_POST['partner_country'];

            $sql = "UPDATE poslovni_partneri 
                     SET 
                     Partner_name     = '$partnername', 
                     Partner_street   = '$partnerstreet', 
                     Partner_zip      = '$partnerzip', 
                     Partner_city     = '$partnercity', 
                     Partner_country  = '$partnercountry' 
                     WHERE Partner_id = '$id'";

        // Prepare statement
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);

        // execute the query
        $stmt->execute();

        }

        echo'
        <form method="POST" target="_parent" >
        <table id="table_id" class="display">
        <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Partner name</th>
              <th>Partner street</th>
              <th>Partner zip</th>
              <th>Partner city</th>
              <th>Partner country</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>';

        $id = $_GET['Partner_id'];              

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM poslovni_partneri WHERE Partner_id LIKE '$id'";
        $stmt = $dbh->query($sql);
        $row =$stmt->fetchObject();

        $partner_name    = $row['partner_name'];
        $partner_street  = $row['partner_street'];
        $partner_zip     = $row['partner_zip'];
        $partner_city    = $row['partner_city'];
        $partner_country = $row['partner_country'];

        echo'
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="partner_name" value="'.$partner_name.'">'.$partnername.'</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="partner_street" value="'.$partner_street.'">'.$partnerstreet.'</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="partner_zip" value="'.$partner_zip.'">'.$partnerzip.'</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="partner_city" value="'.$partner_city.'">'.$partnercity.'</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="partner_country" value="'.$partner_country.'">'.$partnercountry.'</td>
        </tr> 
        </tbody>
      </table>


      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <input type="submit" name="submit_upk" value="Uredi" />
      </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
//triggered when modal is about to be shown
$("#update_poslovni").on("show.bs.modal", function(e) {

    //get data-id attribute of the clicked element
    var bookId = $(e.relatedTarget).data("'.$id.'");

    //populate the textbox
    $(e.currentTarget).find("input[name="bookId"]"").val(bookId);
});
</script>';
// ---- Kraj modal-a za update poslovnih korisnika ---- //
?>
```

Comment: where's your "onclick" event handler? Which opens the modal?

Comment: i dont have it, i have another modal witch opens when i want to insert and it works without onclick?? what do you think?

Comment: ok you have `<a....>edit</a>`, how do you get/expect it to open the modal? how does it happen? we need to add something to that code to stop it from refreshing the page

Comment: i need to edit script under modal, right? can you help me

Comment: You havent shown us all the code. Modal opening javascript needed

Comment: i think i pasted it, in second box all the way down, in script tags

Comment: Yes there's a script, but what it does? just two lines there: defines `bookId` and puts the value into the input. Where' the scripts that open the modal itself?

Comment: that is the problem i don't know how to do that, i need to open modal and show $_GET id

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.
You will need jQueryUI library for this.

First of all, add a class name for the link, like:

```
<a class="update_poslovni" ....
```

Then, the JavaScript:

```
<script>
    $(function(){

        $("a.update_poslovni").click(function(e) 
        {
            event.preventDefault(); // for the <a href="#" not to fire
            var bookId = $(this).data("book-id");
            $("#update_poslovni").find('input[name="bookId"]').val(bookId);
            $("#update_poslovni").dialog({modal: true});
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Still the same, i press the button and nothing happens, i only get id in url
"http://localhost/zadatak_senso index.php?poslovni_korisnici#update_poslovni=34"

Comment: I updated. My bad, I didn't see what's the event listener was targeted to.

Comment: no, still does not work! i get id in url but when i press edit modal does not open

Comment: would help if you listed the complete code as it is now, or gave the URL where I could check it

Answer (score 0):

Use [**BootboxJS**](http://bootboxjs.com/#examples) and prompt component. Check the example and use for you need.